# Callback Ready of Polymer stops the loading of my Component

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x

Im creating my Polymer App and I need to use the [Ready callback](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements) to initiate some events and stuff. The problem is that if I add the following code:

```
ready() {
  console.log("App is ready!");
}
```

the app doesnt load correctly, it stops before loading completely.
For example: I use some kind of canvas and they are not created if I add the function.
Last thing in the console is the log of the function ready "App is ready!".

Comment: Did you forget to call super.ready()?

Comment: It worked!! Im new to Polymer. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call

```
super.ready()
```

method.
You must call the superclass method. This is required so Polymer can hook into the element's lifecycle.

Example:

```
ready() {
  super.ready();
  // …
}
```